# The following packages have unmet dependencies: mysql-server

Tags: lubuntu, mysql

I tried to install mysql on my ubuntu16.04 for a django project. The installation has some problem with some existing files, getting this error:

```
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get -f install` which gives this error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
grep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.2 to 5.7.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.7, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried to uninstall the package and purge and clean but getting the first error, hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What command did you use to install?

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: Are you sure you want to get rid of mariadb? if so, follow the instructions here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/659965/167115

Comment: tried what is mentioned on the links, but still the same error

Comment: You ran: `sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag`? Did you get an error when you ran this command?

Comment: It appears that you may be affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1490071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: when you run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, review the packages to be uninstalled before accepting the changes just to make sure it's not going to uninstall something you want to keep.

If you did not manually install any proprietary drivers like for nvidia, run the following commands:

```
sudo touch /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you did manually install any proprietary drivers like nvidia, run these commands instead:

```
sudo touch /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Please post any errors, thanks!